# sqlite matching on a number

Tags: sql, sqlite

I can't seem to find a good way to match on an integer in SQLite without writing them all out, for example I'm looking to do something like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM numbers
WHERE SUBSTR(numbers 1, 1) LIKE ':d'
```

But the above doesnt work and various versions of it either.

I can get it to work with:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM numbers
WHERE SUBSTR(numbers 1, 1) IN ("1","2","3" [etc])
```

but this seems verbose.

Comment: What do you mean by *match on an integer*?

Comment: You can use `regex`

Comment: Im trying but i cant achieve it. any anwsers welcome

Comment: @Popeye Not without jumping through hoops, depending on your environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count the number of rows where the column `number` starts with a digit:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM numbers
WHERE SUBSTR(numbers, 1, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
```

Answer (score 2):

also since found this too work too:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM numbers
WHERE numbers GLOB '[0-9]*'
```